# Injecting a dynamic value into a bean's constructor-arg tag

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a 3d party library that takes a password as a constructor args for a class defined as a Spring bean.

```
<bean class="com.thirdparty.CoolClass" id="coolClassId">
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="clearTextPassword" />
</bean>
```

But I have a problem ... security policy forbids me to have a clear text password.  So I can setup another bean that takes an encrypted password and decrypts it.

```
@Component("decryptor") 
public class DecryptorService {

  public String decrypt(String encryptedString) { 
   ///
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to up my XML so that the constructor-arg gets its value by passing an encrypted property to this DecryptorService?

Comment: If not clear text password. Where do you configure your password then?
it has to be somewhere right ?

Comment: Sure - our properties have an encrypted password, which we then decrypt and pass in.  That is the point of the "DecryptorService"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have write access to your side of the code.
Create a `@Configuration` class with a `@Bean` method like below

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig {
    @Autowired DecryptorService decryptorService;
    @Autowired Properties props;

    @Bean
    public String clearTextPassword() {
        decryptorService.decrypt(props.getEncryptedPassword());
    }
}
```

Then change your bean definition to use ref

```
<bean class="com.thirdparty.CoolClass" id="coolClassId">
   <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clearTextPassword" />
</bean>
```